# Three.js. Finding neighboring vertices within radius

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js

I've been looking for a way to find the the vertices within a certain radius from a given point. One way to this is brute force. After selection of a point (raypicking), loop over all vertices, check whether it is within a set radius and voila. However, this tends to get quite slow for models with lots of vertices.

What I would want to do is use raypicking to select a point on the model. This would give me the face this point is on. Then from that face I can get the vertices belonging to that face. These vertices can be "shared" over faces. This might allow me to forward search from this point, flagging visited vertices and stop whenever the distance reaches the set maximum (radius). However, from what I can see from a dump of the geometry I can get the vertices belonging to a face directly, but there's no way to get the faces that a vertex belongs to. That is without preprocessing. Am I right here, or did I miss something?

Comment: See if these help you: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_octree.html and http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_octree_raycasting.html

Comment: Ah yes, I have actually implemented that octree already and it did not give me quite what I had hoped for. I added only a single mesh (sphere) to the octree with useFaces set to true. Then when I cast a ray to find an intersection point and then do a search with a radius around that point I'd expect to get what I want. However, the faces that are found are all over the sphere, yet most of them close to the intersection point. And, it is super slow. It takes about 4-5 seconds to do a single search.

Comment: If you have not solved this, and are still interested. You could try a search algorithm to start at the current vertex and recursively move out until you pass a threshold. The issue at the core is that there is no relative information in the array of vectors. Depending on the way the mesh was created the vectors could be in a nonsensical order.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to recursively get all touching faces on a mesh in order to fully select "mesh islands". Sounds like a similar use-case to yours.